# Unable to change SSH port on Almalinux/CentOS 8 with selinux present

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, selinux, centos8

I am trying to change the SSH port on a VPS using Almalinux. I followed this [guide](https://monovm.com/blog/how-to-change-ssh-port-on-centos/#How-to-Change-SSH-Port-in-CentOS-8) but have not been able to.

These are the output I receive when try to SSH using both 22 and the new port respectively.

```
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 23498: Connection timed out
```

Here is the port declaration in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
...
Port 23498 22
...
```

Running `semanage port -l | grep ssh` gives the following output.

```
ssh_port_t                     tcp      23498, 22
```

Restarting using `service sshd restart` with the new port yields the following output.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart sshd.service
Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status sshd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the output of `systemctl status sshd.service`.

```
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-02-25 17:26:08 CET; 34s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 25872 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS $CRYPTO_POLICY (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 25872 (code=exited, status=255)

Feb 25 17:26:08 xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: sshd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 25 17:26:08 xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: sshd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 25 17:26:08 xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
```

Changing the port causes normal SSH to break as well. Commenting out the `Port` in the `sshd_config` and restarting `sshd` allows access via SSH again. I have also tried reinstalling the `openssh-server` after changing the ports but to no avail. The ports are allowed through the uncomplicated firewall. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Port 23498
Port 22
```

instead of

```
Port 23498
```

### Edit:

It seems firewalld was running as well as ufw. Having that unconfigured meant my ports were getting blocked.

Comment: I split the port declaration in the `sshd_config`. Port 22 is now working but port 23498 is not -  `ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 23498: Connection timed out`. Here is the SSH command I'm using `ssh someusername@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 23498`

Comment: Check `netstat -lnptu | grep 23498`. Also check for any errors in `journalctl -e`.

Comment: `command not found: netstat`.  It says the following that are relevant to ports: ` Server listening on :: port 22.`; ` Server listening on :: port 23498.`. I can't find anything else that is relevant or has `error` written anywhere.

Comment: Check that port 23498 is allowed through ufw. Also check that firewalld is not installed.

Comment: The ports are allowed through ufw. Firewalld was running. I guess it was blocking the ports since I didn't do anything about that. I can now SSH through both ports. Thank you so much.